# ftp fails in AIX startup

Tags: aix, ssl, ftp, init-script

I have a script in AIX that runs a `ftp` to make a FTPS connection to another host running vsftpd server.

```
/usr/bin/ftp -snv host 8081 <<END_SCRIPT 
debug
user anonymous pass
passive
binary
debug
quote pwd
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

When i run the above script normally from a shell it works fine.

**Working output**

```
Connected to host.
220 secure FTP service
Debugging on (debug=1).
---> AUTH TLS
234 Proceed with negotiation.
TLS Auth Entered.
TLS handshake succeeded, though Server signed it's own cert!
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
```

But if i add the same script to `/etc/rc.d` or `/etc/inittab`, the script fails to make SSL negotiation and fails.

**Error output when run from init scripts**

```
Connected to host.
220 secure FTP service
234 Proceed with negotiation.
Ftp configuration failed
ERROR  Error setting BIO object for the control connection
FTP: Unable to authenticate to Server.
TLS Auth Entered.
Passive mode on.
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection
```

I am not sure whether it has to do with any environment settings not being present during init scripts execution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My guess is when you're running the script by hand, it's authenicating using your userid. However, when it's run by the system, the userid is most likely root and the connection is most likely being denied by ftpusers. But there could other reasons.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configure-aix-ftpd-use-authoritative-server-certificate

Comment: @CinaedSimson - I am using `anonymous` connection and hence no authentication is involved in either cases.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - I did see this page and i am already creating the mentioned `~/.ftpcnf` file and passing proper arguments.

Comment: Are you running it under the same user in each scenario?

Comment: yes. Running as `root` in both the scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of debugging, the issue was that environment variables were not set when started in init scripts and for reasons unknown to me `ftp` requires `$HOME` variable to be set.

After changing the script to export `$HOME`, the `ftp` works fine.